# ¿Cómo obtengo el ID actual al elemento de un formulario? PHP MySQL

Tags: php

**¿Cómo puedo saber el ID del elemento que se está creando?** Es decir, creo un nuevo elemento mediante un formulario y tengo que saber el ID de ese formulario, el n+1.

Por ejemplo: si ya tengo guardados en la base de datos 6 elementos, ¿cómo se que el elemento que estoy creando o el nuevo dato que estoy creando en el formulario es el número 7?

¿La otra opción sería que al pulsar "Añadir cabaña" se obtenga el ID o no se podría?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
donde idcabana es auto_increment

Al pulsar en "Guardar", ¿dónde obtengo el id de este elemento? (idcabana)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código PHP funciones anadirCabana anadirImagen:**

```
static public function anadirCabana($nombre, $capacidad, $descripcion, $precio){
        $ejecucion = self::Conexion();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO cabanas (nombre, capacidad, descripcion, precio) VALUES ('".$nombre."', ".$capacidad.", '".$descripcion."', ".$precio.")";
        $ok = $ejecucion->exec($sql);
        if($ok==1){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }


    static public function anadirImagen($ruta, $idcabana){
        $ejecucion = self::Conexion();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO imagenes (ruta, idcabana) VALUES ('".$ruta."', ".$idcabana.")";
        $ok = $ejecucion->exec($sql);
        if($ok==1){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Código HTML + PHP:**

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
    require_once "Clases/BD.php";
    require_once "Clases/Cabanas.php";
    require_once "conexion.php";

    //Iniciar una nueva sesión o reanudar la existente.
    session_start();
    //Si existe la sesión "administrador"..., la guardamos en una variable.
    if (isset($_SESSION['administrador'])){
        $administrador = $_SESSION['administrador'];
    }

    //Si pulsamos el botón "Guardar"... 
    //Realizamos el "INSERT" antes que el "SELECT" para que se actualice la tabla correctamente.
    if(isset($_POST["guardar"])){
        $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
        $capacidad = $_POST["capacidad"];
        $descripcion = $_POST["descripcion"];
        $precio = $_POST["precio"];

        //Llamamos al método "anadirCabana" y le pasamos los parámetros del formulario.
        BD::anadirCabana($nombre, $capacidad, $descripcion, $precio);


        //$_FILES: Variables de subida de ficheros HTTP.
        //Subir el nombre de una imagen.
        if (!isset($_FILES["imagen"]) || $_FILES["imagen"]["error"] > 0){
            echo "Ha ocurrido un error. Inténtelo de nuevo...";
        }else{
            //Comprobamos si la extensión el fichero es de tipo imagen y menor de 16MB.
            $permitidos = array("image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png");
            $limite_kb = 16384;
            //Si la extensión del fichero a subir, coincide con la de permitidos...
            if (in_array($_FILES['imagen']['type'], $permitidos) && $_FILES['imagen']['size'] <= $limite_kb * 1024){
                //Guardamos la imagen como archivo local en "$imagen_temporal". [tmp_name] sería para archivo temporal (carpeta tmp de Xampp).
                $imagen_temporal = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];

                //Tipo de extensión.
                $tipo = $_FILES['imagen']['type'];

                //Escapamos los caracteres para que se puedan almacenar en la base de datos correctamente.
                $imagen_temporal = mysql_escape_string($imagen_temporal);
                $ruta_imagen = $imagen_temporal; 

                //Insertamos en la base de datos.
                $sql = BD::anadirImagen($ruta_imagen, $idcabana); //Como le paso el id actual al pulsar en guardar...
                //Si encuentra un resultado, OK.
                if($sql==1){
                    echo "El archivo ha sido copiado exitosamente.";
                }else{
                    echo "Ocurrió algun error al copiar el archivo.";
                }
            }else{
                echo "Formato de archivo no permitido o excede el tamaño límite de $limite_kb Kbytes.";
            }
        }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Panel del administrador</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validar_formulario_cabana.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ocultar_mostrar.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="sesion_administrador">
            <?php 
            if(isset($_SESSION['administrador'])){
                echo "Bienvenido ".$administrador."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                echo "<a href='salir_administrador.php?salir=1'>Salir</a>"; //GET
                //_REQUEST = $_POST o $_GET
                if(isset($_REQUEST["salir"])){
                    unset($_SESSION["administrador"]);
                    header("Refresh:0; url=iniciar_sesion_administrador.php");
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>

        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="tabla_datos_cabana" id="tabla_datos_cabana" method="POST">
            <div id="mostrar_cabanas">
            <br/><br/><br/>
                <table class="table table-striped" name="tabla" width="600" border="2" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" style="font-size: 10pt">
                    <center>
                        <tr>
                            <thead style="background-color:#A9F5A9">
                                <td width=\"150\">
                                    <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>ID Cabaña</center></b></font>
                                </td>
                                <td width=\"250\">
                                    <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>Nombre</center></b></font>
                                </td>
                                <td width=\"150\">
                                    <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>Modificar</center></b></font>
                                </td>
                                <td width=\"150\">
                                    <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>Eliminar</center></b></font>
                                </td>
                            </thead>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                        $datos = BD::obtenerCabanas();
                        foreach($datos as $cabana){
                            echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td width=\"150\"><font face=\"verdana\"><font size='2'><center>".$cabana->getIdcabana()."</center></font></font></td>";
                                echo "<td width=\"250\"><font face=\"verdana\"><font size='2'><center>".$cabana->getNombre()."</center></font></font></td>";
                                echo "<td width=\"150\"><font face=\"verdana\"><font size='2'><center>"?> 
                                    <a href="modificar.php?idcabana=<?=$cabana->getIdcabana();?>">
                                        <img src="imagenes/modificar.png" height='24' width='26' onmouseover="this.src='imagenes/modificar_in.png';" onmouseout="this.src='imagenes/modificar.png';">
                                    </a> <?php "</center></font></font></td>";
                                echo "<td width=\"150\"><center><input type='checkbox' name='marcados[]' id='marcados[]' value=".$cabana->getIdcabana()."></center>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </center>
                </table>

                <!-- Botón NUEVA cabaña -->
                <div class="boton_anadir" class="table-responsive" align="left">
                    <font face="verdana">
                        <b><input type="button" style="width:200px; height:28px;" name="nueva_cabana" id="nueva_cabana" value="Añadir cabaña" /></b>
                    </font>
                </div>

                <!-- Botón ELIMINAR cabaña/s -->
                <div class="boton_eliminar" class="table-responsive" align="left">
                    <font face="verdana">
                        <b><input type="submit" style="width:200px; height:28px;" name="eliminar_cabanas" id="eliminar_cabanas" onclick="return confirm('¿Deseas realmente eliminar estas cabañas?');" value="Eliminar cabañas" /></b>
                    </font><br/>
                </div>

                <?php
                //Si pulsamos el botón "Eliminar cabañas"...
                if(isset($_POST['eliminar_cabanas'])){
                    if(empty($_POST['marcados'])){
                        echo "<h4><center>No se ha seleccionado ninguna cabaña.</center></h4>";
                    }else{
                        foreach($_POST['marcados'] as $valor){
                            //Nos conectamos a la base de datos.
                            $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "osmarrural");
                            //Realizamos la consulta.
                            $sql = sprintf("DELETE FROM cabanas WHERE idcabana='%d'", $valor);
                            $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
                            /*
                            $mysqli = new mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "osmarrural");
                            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM cabanas WHERE idcabana = ?");
                            $stmt->bind_param('i', $valor);
                            $stmt->execute();
                            $stmt->close();
                            */
                        }
                        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; URL=panel_administrador.php\">";
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </form>

        <br/><br/><br/>
        <!-- Añadir una cabaña -->
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="anadir" id="anadir" method="POST" onsubmit="return validar_formulario_cabana();">
            <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label>
                <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" />
            <br/><br/>
            <label for="capacidad">Capacidad: </label>
                <?php
                echo "<select name='capacidad'>";
                for($i=1; $i<11; $i++){
                    if($i==1){
                        echo "<option value='$i' selected='selected'>$i</option>";
                    }else{
                        echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
                    }
                }
                echo "</select>";
                ?>
            <br/><br/>
            <label for="descripcion">Descripción: </label>
                <input type="text" id="descripcion" name="descripcion" />
            <br/><br/>
            <label for="precio">Precio: </label>
                <input type="text" id="precio" name="precio" onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event);" />
            <br/><br/>

            <!-- Subir archivo -->
            <label for="imagen">Imagen:</label>
                <input type="file" name="imagen" id="imagen" /> <!-- multiple="multiple" -->
            <br/><br/>

            <input type="submit" value="Guardar" id="guardar" name="guardar" />
            <input type="reset" value="Resetear" id="resetear" name="resetear" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Para que necesitas el id antes de guardarlo?

Comment: Para enviar ese id a otra tabla para guardar el campo imagen, el campo imagen corresponde al idcabana

Comment: Después de ejecutar la inserción, puedes preguntar a la conexión por el último ID insertado: [$new_id = $mysqli->insert_id;](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Comment: `SELECT TOP (1) idcabana FROM cabanas ORDER BY idcabana DESC`

Comment: Si al cargar el formulario ejecutas esto te devuelve el ultimo id que se encuentra insertado(claro siempre y cuando no elimines registros) ya solo guardas esto en una variable y a la hora de mandarlo a otra tabla le sumas 1

Comment: No necesito al cargarlo, necesito al pulsar "Guardar", al mismo efecto para guardar dos datos en diferentes tablas. Una tabla guarda todos los datos en la tabla "cabanas" y la otra tabla, necesita el idcabana del momento, para guardar la foto en la tabla "imagenes".

Comment: Añade el código de como estas guardando el registro. Php provee funciones para tal fin cuando el PK es autógena radón, ejemplo http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: Añadido! @Xerif

Comment: @omaza1990 por favor tené cuidado para no crear [meta etiquetas](/help/tagging). La etiqueta `id` no debería existir siquiera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar el mysqli_insert_id siempre y cuando el ID sea AUTO_INCREMENT y estes usando INSERT o UPDATE

Ejemplo:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO myCity VALUES (NULL, 'Stuttgart', 'DEU', 'Stuttgart', 617000)";
mysqli_query($link, $query);

printf ("Nuevo registro con el id %d.\n", mysqli_insert_id($link));
```

Mayor información: http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: El problema que tengo es que tengo las dos funciones separadas, es decir, una función para anadirCabana() y otra para anadirImagen(), al pulsar "Guardar" los datos X se guardan en cada una de las funciones a la vez.

Comment: Estoy amoldando tu código del INSERT en mi aplicación, ¿link qué es en tu código?

Comment: @omaza1990 `$link` = `$conexion`, es decir, es tu conexión. Quedaría así `mysqli_insert_id($conexion)`.

Comment: En mi caso tengo un método para hacer la conexión en el fichero BD.php static public function Conexion(){
        $con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=osmarrural", "root", "root");
        return $con;
    }

Comment: ¿Alguna ayuda referente a mi código? No sé porque no me obtiene el valor del ID actual.